# Highlighted column and row not working. How to resolve it?

Tags: tables, colortbl, rowcolor

I need to highlight some columns and rows in the table. But the following code is not working. So kindly help me to resolve the issue. I am using miktex with winedt. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[CEJMed,PDF]{cej}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pbsi}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}[defn]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{cor}[defn]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[defn]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[defn]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{rem}[defn]{Remark}
\newtheorem{ex}[defn]{Example}
\newtheorem{re}[defn]{Result}
 \newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
 \newcommand{\To}{\longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{H}}
 \newcommand{\newsarrow}{\nearrow \kern-12pt \swarrow \kern-12pt \smallsetminus}
 \newcommand{\nupdownarrow}{\updownarrow \kern-11pt -}
\allowdisplaybreaks


\title{Article title}

%\articletype{Research Article} % Research Article, Review Article, Communication, Erratum




\author{Author 1\inst{1,}\email{@gmail.com} and
Author 2\inst{1}
       }

\shortauthor{Author 1 and Author 2}

\institute{\inst{1}
          Affiliation of Authors
                    }

\abstract{In this paper....
}

\keywords{keywords1, keywords2, keywords3, }

\msc{47A63.}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{41}


\section{Introduction}

\strutlongstacks{T}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\columncolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 & $D_1$ & {\dots} & $D_j$ & {\dots} & $D_n$ & Supply \\ \hline
$O_1$ & \Centerstack{$c_{11}$\\ $d_{11}$ $\left(x_{11}\right)$\\ $p_{11}$} & {\dots} & \Centerstack{$c_{1j}$\\ $d_{1j}$ $\left(x_{1j}\right)$\\ $p_{1j}$} & {\dots} & \Centerstack{$c_{1n}$\\ $d_{1n}$ $\left(x_{1n}\right)$\\ $p_{1n}$} & $a_1$ \\ \hline
$\vdots$ &  & {\dots} &  & {\dots} &  &  \\ \hline
$O_i$ & \Centerstack{$c_{i1}$\\ $d_{i1}$  $\left(x_{i1}\right)$\\ $p_{i1}$} & {\dots} & \Centerstack{$c_{ij}$\\ $d_{ij}$ $\left(x_{ij}\right)$\\ $p_{ij}$} & {\dots} & \Centerstack{$c_{in}$\\ $d_{in}$ $\left(x_{in}\right)$\\ $p_{in}$} & $a_i$ \\ \hline
$\vdots$ &  & {\dots} &  & {\dots} &  &  \\ \hline
$O_m$ & \Centerstack{$c_{m1}$\\ $d_{m1}$ $\left(x_{m1}\right)$\\ $p_{m1}$} & {\dots} & \Centerstack{$c_{mj}$\\ $d_{mj}$ $\left(x_{mj}\right)$\\ $p_{mj}$} & {\dots} & \Centerstack{$c_{mn}$\\ $d_{mn}$ $\left(x_{mn}\right)$\\ $p_{mn}$} & $a_m$ \\ \hline
Demand & $b_1$ &  & $b_j$ &  & $b_n$ &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please share us the exact class file.

Comment: Where did you get the document class from?

Comment: The above mentioned code is not working. It is showing several errors.

Comment: the document class available here http://sendanywhe.re/3O7X7ZYN

Comment: There is a line '\includegraphics[width=1in]{123}` in our file `cej.cls` and we have not that file...

Comment: that file is journal logo file you may fill with any image